# belongsTo() function not working

Tags: laravel, relation

I am trying to make a relation with my Character table and Account table but when I add the `belongsTo()` method I don't see the data of Account added to it.

So this is my Character model:

```
class Character extends Model
{
    //Get players by level
    public function scopeGetPlayersByLevel($query){
        return $query->orderBy('level', 'desc')->get();
    }

    //Get players by zulie
    public function scopeGetPlayersByZulie($query){
        return $query->orderBy('zuly', 'desc')->get();
    }

    //Get online status
    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'username', 'account_name');
    }
}
```

Account model:

```
class Account extends Model
{
    //Get online players
    public function scopeGetOnlinePlayers($query){
        return $query->where('online', 1);
    }

    //Get online staff
    public function scopeGetOnlineStaff($query){
        return $query->where('online', 1)->where('accesslevel', 350);
    }

    public function characters(){
        return $this->hasMany(Character::class, 'account_name', 'username');
    }
}
```

And I add the variable in my controller like this:

use App\Character;

```
class RankingController extends Controller
{
    function index(){
        $players = Character::find(100);
        return $players;
    }
}
```

Table structure:

```
accounts:
  - username

characters:
  - account_name //foreign key
```

The result of `$players` is only the character data. Why doesn't the account data add to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do is you are trying to get a player and all their characters.

try

```
function index(){
    $player = Account::find(1);
    return $player->characters;
}
```

Find the account of a character

```
$caracter = Character::find(1);
return $caracter->account;
```

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. I'm trying to find the account of the character

Comment: That works thank you. I thought `return $character` would show that the account object would be inside it. Any idea on why that's not the case?

Comment: Sort of. You can just return $caracter. and in your view you can do `$caracter->account->username` and it will display the username.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Get online status
    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_name', 'username');
    }
```

Comment: "That works thank you. I thought return $character would show that the account object would be inside it. Any idea on why that's not the case? ". For this case use $caracter = Character::find(1)->with('account');